# Who mourns over Moab in Isaiah 15-16?

Tags: isaiah

In Isaiah 15-16, Isaiah makes a pronouncement against Moab. Some parts make me think this is written in God's voice, and words like "I" refer to God:

Isaiah 15:9

> The Waters of Dibon are full of blood, but I will bring on Dibon even more than this

Isaiah 16:10

> I have put an end to the shouting

There are also verses where the speaker mourns for Moab:

Isaiah 15:5

> My heart cries out over Moab

Isaiah 16:9

> So I join with Jazer to weep for the vines of Sibmah; I drench Heshbon and Elealeh with my tears.

Isaiah 16:11

> Therefore I moan like the sound of a lyre for Moab, as does my innermost being for Kir-heres.

In the verses where the speaker mourns for Moab, should we understand that as Isaiah or God mourning?

(Quotations from CSB.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speaker is God, not the prophet. Whether this is actually a prophecy of Isaiah, however, is uncertain, for after it concludes, Isaiah adds in vs. 13:

> That is the word the Lord spoke against Moab in times past.

The Moabites were the Israelites' relatives, descendants of Abraham's nephew Lot. God mourns for them and urges the leaders of Judah to care for Moabite refugees, especially women whose husbands have died in the recent battles:

> The daughters of Moab are
> at the fords of the Arnon.  Offer counsel, take their part;
> at high noon make your shade like the night; Hide the outcasts,
> do not betray the fugitives.  Let the outcasts of Moab live with you,
> be their shelter from the destroyer. (Is. 16:2-4)

In addition to simple compassion for those who suffer, this prophecy also seems to express the hope that some of the Moabites, like David's ancestor Ruth, will convert and join Judah under David's descendants. However, this will happen only after the Moabites have "warn themselves out on the high places" (16:12), a reference to their worship of other gods.

> A throne shall be set up in mercy,
> and on it shall sit in fidelity,
> in David’s tent, A judge upholding right,
> prompt to do justice.  (vs. 5)

**Conclusion**: It is God who mourns in these verses. Isaiah, perhaps quoting an earlier prophet, expresses what God was feeling.

Answer (score 1):

Let there be no doubt about the fact that:

- "**God is love**" (1 John 4:8, 16), and
- "God so loved the world ... " (John 3:16)

Further, we read in Eze 33:11

> Say to them: ‘As surely as I live, **declares the Lord GOD, I take no
> pleasure in the death of the wicked**, but rather that the wicked
> should turn from their ways and live. Turn! Turn from your evil ways!
> For why should you die, O house of Israel?’

Thus, because God loves all people and takes no pleasure in the death of the wicked, it is little wonder that God morns the death of the wicked; in this instance, Moab's rejection of God and His promises as recorded in Isa 15, 16.  Recall that:

> 2 Peter 3:9 - The Lord is not slow in keeping His promise as some
> understand slowness, but is patient with you, not wanting anyone to
> perish but everyone to come to repentance.

The sad fact is, despite God's earnest desire that all repent, not all will and some people will be lost.