Is God telling Judah to take in the refugees of Moab? Isaiah 16
In the prophecy against Moab in Isaiah 15 and 16, it is clear that God is punishing Moab, but also weeping for their demise.
In Isaiah 16:3-4 NIV, Moab pleads with Judah to take in her refugees. Then in Isaiah 16:4-5 NIV comes to talk about that the Messiah will come and establish a throne and rule with justice.

3“Make up your mind,” Moab says.
“Render a decision.
Make your shadow like night—
at high noon.
Hide the fugitives,
do not betray the refugees.
4 Let the Moabite fugitives stay with you;
be their shelter from the destroyer.”
The oppressor will come to an end,
and destruction will cease;
the aggressor will vanish from the land.
5 In love a throne will be established;
in faithfulness a man will sit on it—
one from the house[a] of David—
one who in judging seeks justice
and speeds the cause of righteousness.

I am wondering if God commands Judah to take in the Moabites or if He is defering their rescue to the day of the Messiah. I am confused if it is the first, because Moab is saying it and not God, but I am also confused if God is defering rescue to the coming of the Messiah, since it is not clearly stated whether Judah will accept the plees for refuge.
I was wondering if there might be answers in the original Hebrew as well that we are not picking up on in English.
Thanks

Welcome to the group Lauren. See related question here. I do not think this question is a duplicate exactly, but based on a moderator's suggestion to check for duplicates before answering I will refer you to that question rather than responding directly.

The Enduring Word Commentary may shed some light on the passage:
If nothing else then Isaiah’s plea to Judah to hide the outcasts and not betray the refugees, suggests a moral imperative for Judah to act with compassion and justice.

(3) Isaiah’s word to Judah as she observes Moab under judgment.
a. Hide the outcasts: Here, in the compassion of his prophecy, Isaiah
pleads with the rulers of Judah to hide the outcasts of Moab. Again,
his great sympathies are probably due to the connection between Moab
and the royal house of David.
b. Do not betray him who escapes: Isaiah wanted Judah to be a place of
refuge and protection for Moab under judgment. This is exactly what
the church should when people receive the judgment that fits their
rebellion against God. If they humbly flee for refuge among God’s
people, the church should be a place that will hide the outcasts and
receive him who escapes, never to betray them.

This is not the only place that this moral imperative of taking care of refugees and foreigners is presented in scripture:

Exodus 22:21 - “You shall not wrong a sojourner or oppress him,
for you were sojourners in the land of Egypt.
Leviticus 19:33-34 - “When a stranger sojourns with you in your
land, you shall not do him wrong. 34 You shall treat the stranger who
sojourns with you as the native among you, and you shall love him as
yourself, for you were strangers in the land of Egypt: I am the Lord
your God.
Deuteronomy 10:18-19 - He executes justice for the fatherless and the
widow, and loves the sojourner, giving him food and clothing. 19 Love
the sojourner, therefore, for you were sojourners in the land of
Egypt.
Matthew 25:35-40 - For I was hungry and you gave me food, I was
thirsty and you gave me drink, I was a stranger and you welcomed me,
36 I was naked and you clothed me, I was sick and you visited me, I
was in prison and you came to me.’ 37 Then the righteous will answer
him, saying, ‘Lord, when did we see you hungry and feed you, or
thirsty and give you drink? 38 And when did we see you a stranger and
welcome you, or naked and clothe you? 39 And when did we see you sick
or in prison and visit you?’ 40 And the King will answer them,
‘Truly, I say to you, as you did it to one of the least of these my
brothers, you did it to me.’

The Enduring Word Commentary continues:


(4-5) A plea for refuge among Moab in the day of the righteous King.

a. Let My outcasts dwell with you, O Moab: This is a sudden and curious change of focus. In Isaiah 16:3, Judah was counseled to receive the outcasts of Moab. Now, Moab is asked to receive the
outcasts of Judah. Bultema thinks that Isaiah 16:4-5 is an end-times
prophecy of how Moab will be a place of refuge for Jews escaping the
fury of the Antichrist after the abomination of desolation.
i. In a coming day, Israel, will flee from the fury of the Antichrist
and will find refuge in places like Moab (Revelation 12:6, 12:13-14).
They will be protected from the face of the spoiler until devastation
ceases and the oppressors are consumed out of the land.
b. In mercy the throne will be established: In those end times, the
throne of the Messiah will be established, and the Messiah Himself
will sit on the throne: One will sit on it in truth, in the tabernacle
of David. His reign will be wonderful, judging and seeking justice and
hastening righteousness.


Upvoted. I would add that the text indicates that Isaiah is actually quoting a prophecy from previous times.  See 16.13. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/87254/who-mourns-over-moab-in-isaiah-15-16

The Book of Isaiah is a collection of prophecies, featuring a variety of oracles, prophecies, and reports, traditionally accredited to Isaiah. Chapters 15 and 16 may not describe a single prophecy. Isaiah 16:13 is particularly notable:

"This is the word the Lord has already spoken concerning Moab" (NIV)

However, it is unclear whether the term "This" refers to the entire context of Isaiah 15:1-16:12 or only a portion of it. It is also worth noting that Jeremiah 48 contains remarkably similar content to Isaiah 15 and 16:



Book of Isaiah (NIV)
Book of Jeremiah (NIV)




15:2-3 ....Every head is shaved and every beard cut off. 3 In the streets they wear sackcloth; on the roofs and in the public squares they all wail, prostrate with weeping.
48:37 Every head is shaved and every beard cut off; every hand is slashed and every waist is covered with sackcloth.


15:4-6 Heshbon and Elealeh cry out, their voices are heard all the way to Jahaz. Therefore the armed men of Moab cry out, and their hearts are faint. 5 My heart cries out over Moab; her fugitives flee as far as Zoar, as far as Eglath Shelishiyah. They go up the hill to Luhith, weeping as they go; on the road to Horonaim they lament their destruction. 6 The waters of Nimrim are dried up.........
48:34 “The sound of their cry rises from Heshbon to Elealeh and Jahaz, from Zoar as far as Horonaim and Eglath Shelishiyah, for even the waters of Nimrim are dried up.


16:6-7 We have heard of Moab’s pride—how great is her arrogance!—of her conceit, her pride and her insolence; but her boasts are empty. 7 Therefore the Moabites wail, they wail together for Moab. Lament and grieve for the raisin cakes of Kir Hareseth
48:29-31 “We have heard of Moab’s pride—how great is her arrogance!—of her insolence, her pride, her conceit and the haughtiness of her heart. 30 I know her insolence but it is futile,” declares the Lord, “and her boasts accomplish nothing. 31 Therefore I wail over Moab, for all Moab I cry out, I moan for the people of Kir Hareseth.



The total dissolution of Moab occurred in 582BC, five years after the fall of Jerusalem. It is unlikely that Isaiah 16:1-4 describes an event from that time, as Judah no longer existed to receive tribute from Moab or to offer refuge. This passage likely refers to a much earlier period, possibly during the time of Isaiah. Isaiah 16:5 is particularly remarkable:

In love a throne will be established;
in faithfulness a man will sit on it—
one from the house[a] of David—
one who in judging seeks justice
and speeds the cause of righteousness.

There is no doubt Isaiah 16:5 is a Messianic prophecy. Often, events from the past foreshadow future events. Consider the following verse given to king Ahaz:
Isaiah 7:14 NIV

Therefore the Lord himself will give you (The Hebrew is plural) a sign: The virgin (or young woman) will conceive and give birth to a son, and will call him Immanuel (means "God with us").

This is a double prophecy given to Ahaz and for the future. For Ahaz, it referred to his son Hezekiah, whose name means "God strengthens". The first half of Hezekiah's reign was blessed by the Lord, including the miraculous defeat of Sennacherib, the mighty Assyria king, in the 14th year of Hezekiah's reign.
Moab had became a vassal state of Assyria during the reign of Tiglath-pileser III (745-727BC). After the death of Sargon II, Sennacherib's father, several states in the Levant, including Moab, renounced their allegiance to Assyria. Most notably, Hezekiah of Judah, encouraged by Egypt, joined the rebellion (Isaiah 31). This rebellion subsequently led to Sennacherib's expeditionary forces capturing most of the cities and towns in the Levant and besieging Hezekiah in Jerusalem (Isaiah 36 and 37, 2 Kings 18 and 19). Jerusalem was saved by the Lord's miraculous intervention.
There is no specific reference to the fate of Moab. However, the cities described in Isaiah 15 were in the northern region of Moab. Isaiah 15:7 describes the Moabites carried their wealth across "the Ravine of the Poplars" (NIV), or "Book of the Willows", depending on the translation. Scholars believe this refers to the Zered River, the border between Moab and Edom, indicating that the Moabites fled south, around the southern end of the Dead Sea into Judah. However, there is no reference to Hezekiah receiving Moabite refugees.

The Moabites are protrayed as a tribe against the Lord ("she has defied the Lord" Jeremiah 48:26) and against His chosen people ("Israel the object of your ridicule" Jeremiah 48:27). Yet in 48:47, the Lord says:

“Yet I will restore the fortunes of Moab in days to come,”
declares the Lord. (NIV)

The declaration parallels Isaiah 16:5:

In love a throne will be established;
in faithfulness a man will sit on it—
one from the house of David—
one who in judging seeks justice
and speeds the cause of righteousness. (NIV)

When the wicked repent, their sins will be forgiven, and their righteousness will be restored. This promise in Malachi 4:6 was ultimately fulfilled through Jesus, whose sacrifice reconciled humanity with the Lord.

He will turn the hearts of the parents to their children, and the hearts of the children to their parents.


The OP's opening sentence is both salutary and an excellent summary of this portion of Isaiah:

In the prophecy against Moab in Isaiah 15 and 16, it is clear that God
is punishing Moab, but also weeping for their demise.

First, I fully agree that in Isaiah's time because the earthly dynasty of king David was about to cease, V5 (quoted by the OP) is definitely Messianic - Jesus Christ the Son of David would take the Davidic throne as messiah in the heavenly kingdom of God, Mark 16:19, Eph 1:20, Heb 1:3, 8:1, 12:2, 1 Peter 3:22, Rev 5, etc.
Second, Judgements of God are painful to God as stated elsewhere in Isaiah:

Isaiah 28:21 - The LORD will rise up as he did at Mount Perazim, he
will rouse himself as in the Valley of Gibeon— to do his work, his
strange work, and perform his task, his alien task. [ie, His task of destruction of the wicked according to V22.]

Further, Ezekiel tells us:

Eze 33:11 - Say to them, ‘As surely as I live, declares the Sovereign
LORD, I take no pleasure in the death of the wicked, but rather that
they turn from their ways and live. Turn! Turn from your evil ways!
Why will you die, people of Israel?’

Concerning Isa 16:4, we have several commentators who fully agree with the OP's assertion such as the Pulpit commentary:

Verse 4. - Let mine outcasts dwell with thee, Moab. The change of one
accent will allow of this passage being translated, Let the outcasts
of Moab dwell with thee; and so it is rendered by the LXX., the
Syriac, by Lowth, Gesenius, Hitzig, Ewald, and Mr. Cheyne. Delitzsch
and Dr. Kay agree with the Authorized Version. For the extortioner is
at an end. This seems to be urged as a reason why the protection asked
should be given: it will not be for long - the oppressor is about to
receive chastisement.

